# get top values in select

Tags: sql

I have next ordered table:

```
types        count
soft         7
lite soft    5
middle soft  4
hard soft    3
other        2
```

I need to select top values, sum of witch is 15+ (in my case 7+5+4 > 15) and merge items which lefts in to other:
result should be:

```
types        count
soft         7
lite soft    5
middle soft  4
other        5
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subquery with a cumulative sum:

```
select (case when running_count - count <= 15 then types else 'other' end) as types,
       sum(count)
from (select t.*, sum(count) over (order by count desc) as running_count
      from t
     ) t
group by (case when running_count - count <= 15 then types else 'other' end)
```